# Probability / odds to flop flush or 4 flush

Tags: odds, flush

What are the odds of flopping a flush or 4 flush?

Obviously you need to have suited hole cards.

Comment: What did your fiend Google tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran the numbers and thought it was worth posting

Using [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

flops combin(50, 3) = 19600

3 flush combin(11, 3) = 165 / 19600 = 0.0084183673 = 0.84% = 1/119

2 flush combin(11, 2) = 55
other cards = 39
55 * 39 / 19600 = 0.1094387755 = 11% = 1 / 9

flush or 4 flush = 0.0084183673 + 0.1094387755 = 0.1178571429 = 12% = 1 / 8.5

4 flush hit on the turn = 9 / 47 = 0.1914893617 = 19% = 1 / 5.22

4 flush hit on the river = 8 / 46 = 0.1956521739 = 20% = 1 / 5.11

flush hit on turn or river or both
( 9 flush x 47 other card + combine(9, 2) ) / combin(47, 2) = 0.3496762257 = 35% = 1 / 2.9

flush by the river = 0.063998282 = 6% = 1 / 15.6